# Is it possible to modify high level UI from code while developing UWP XAML application?

Tags: xaml, uwp

For example in browsers I can manipulate DOM from JS.
Are there any analogue API?
Is it possible at all?

Update:
We define UI using XAML while developing UWP application.
Can I change UI defined by XAML or is it fixed forever?

Comment: What do you mean by "high level UI"?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely change the UI at run time.
Add controls, remove controls, change properties, apply transforms or behaviours, restyle things. It's all possible.

As a simple example.
Given this XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="SO33419586.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid x:Name="TheGrid"
          Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock>bye bye</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

we can do the following in code behind:

```
this.TheGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Chartreuse);

this.TheGrid.Children.Clear();
this.TheGrid.Children.Add(new Button {Content = "click me"});
```

When run this creates a view with a green (chartreuse) background and containing a button but no textblock.

The key part here is the `x:Name` assigned in XAML as that makes it simple to reference controls created that way.

Comment: Can you provide link to appropriate API, please?

Comment: thanks for you answer. You give me a hint where I should look to:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj203560.aspx before I spent an hour, but couldn't find it, MSDN is not my preferred documentation.